# PHP include var from file in a file that is then included in other files

Tags: php, include, global, var

I have a blog structured with several different php files (header, footer, main, etc.). I want to create a PHP file called adv.php that contains a var that needs to be retrieved in all the other PHP files. I would like to include the adv.php file ONLY in the header.php, and make sure that the var still works in footer.php, main.php, and so on.

I tried and even with global vars, this doesn't seem to work. How can I fix this? Again, I would like to only include the adv.php file once in header.php and not in every single php file.

EDIT

Here is a simplified version of the code with only relevant parts:

adv.php

```
<?php $ad300_top_right_index = "RTB"; ?>
```

header.php

```
<?php include_once('adv.php');  ?>
```

main.php

```
<?php if  ( $ad300_top_right_index == "RTB" ) { ?>

show code here

<?php } else { ?>

show some other code here

<?php } ?>
```

About the inclusions: it's a Wordpress template, where the resulting page will include header.php and main.php, and header.php includes adv.php. Of course adv.php gets included before I try to use the var in main.php.

Comment: are you retreiving the var after you have included the file containing it?

Comment: include/require act as if the contents of the included file are literally cut&paste into the spot where the `include` directive is. as far as the later code is concerned, there's no difference between including a file and having it literally part of the main file itself. you just have to be aware of PHP's scoping rules.

Comment: Are you attempting to use this variable in a function in one of the other included scripts [Variable Scope in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Yes, the var is called after the include (this is why i choose to add the include in the header).

Comment: @MarcB but it does not seem to work... the adv.php is included in header.php. Calling the var in the header.php works, but it will not work if I call it from another file such as footer.php. Is the only solution to add the include string in every single file that needs to call the var?

Comment: @RiggsFolly no, the var is called outside a function, it's plain PHP code.

Comment: then show a simplified version of your code. we can't debug what we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown any code, but there is NO reason for a var included in one file to not be visible in the other:

a.php

```
<?php
$x = 7;
```

b.php

```
<?php
echo $x, "\n";
```

z.php

```
<?php
echo "#1 - startup\n";
echo $x, "\n";

echo "#2 - including a\n";
include('a.php');

echo "#3 - included\n";
echo $x, "\n";

echo "#4 - including b\n";
include('b.php');

echo "#5 - included\n";
```

Output of running z.php:

```
#1 - startup
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: x in /home/marc/z.php on line 3

#2 - including a
#3 - included
7
#4 - including b
7
#5 - included
```

Note that `7` is output as expected.

If you're not getting your var, then there's something OTHER than php causing the problem, e.g. not understanding scoping rules.

Comment: Thanks! I added the relevant code in my original question. I am probably missing something (I'm not a PHP expert, really). Could the problem be that I'm not echoing the var, but just using it as a hidden string to store a content that I'm then using in a conditional?

Comment: not really, but it is wordpress. are you sure that your include() is being executed at the top-level scope? you may have to declare the var `global`